# Git post-receive hook, send curl commit message to Discord Webhook

Tags: bash, curl, discord, githooks

I am trying to post an information-message in our discord every time someone pushes to the master.

I have a post-receive bash script looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then

        tail=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:'%h %cn: %s%b' $newrev)       
        url='https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/validapikey'
        curl -i \
        -H "Accept: application/json" \
        -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
        -X POST \
        --data  '{"content": "'$tail'"}' $url
    fi
done
```

If I output tail to a file I get the expected string

```
6baf5 user: last commit message
```

but the message does not get posted on discord

If I replace $tail with "hello" it gets posted.

Comment: The idea with discord is pretty nice, I love it man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 suggestions:

a) -d "{\"content\": \"${tail}\"}"

b) You can write this in the same language your project is, like Python or NodeJS, which is always better than bash (use the same name and make it executable)

c) To avoid this to be maintained in each dev machine, you can version this logic inside your repo using https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git or any other too that provides git hook management.

Comment: Additionally, if you can use BitBucket/Pipelines (private repo) or TravisCI (github.com public repo), they do this notification logic just by configuration.

Comment: a) works !  for b) and c) we have a standalone git server where we have the hooks placed, we did not want to install a language just for the hooks but thanks for the suggestions and the solution.